# How to avoid lots of boilerplate in a polymorphic factory pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an abstract `Command` class.  Every `Command` class created from a certain class, `Fetcher`, needs to be endowed with certain properties.  Normally this looks like a factory pattern - `Fetcher` creates a `CommandFactory` that will prepare the `Command` when creating it.  However there are about a dozen derived classes and I don't see how to do this without having a different concrete factory for each concrete class, or a different method `createConcrete1Command` that will have to be extended each time a new `Command` class is created.  Is there any strategy for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if there's a lot of boilerplate code for each Command class, you can extract out the commonality to an AbstractCommand class.

Comment: It's not clear from your description how you know which Command sub-class to create. However, once you have that worked out, perhaps you could make the factory method a static method of each Command sub-class. Common functionality can be kept in one or more methods of the Command base class. That way, when you create the next Command sub-class, you just need to implement the new factory method in the new class, and don't need to touch any existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found to this situation is as follows:

Constructor:

```
public BaseClass(Parameters p); // can be expanded and endowed as necessary; essentially anything a constructor can do can happen here.
```

All derived classes will of course taken a `Parameters` as an argument, however `Parameters` can be extended as necessary with no need to touch the constructor of any derived class.

Comment: This is awesome. By the way, do you realise that a "command" is nothing more than a "function" or "method" call that  doesn't belong to a class (ie trying to do functional programming within an OO language.) Java is annoying (:

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `Class.forName(String)` and `Class.newInstance` to programmatically create new instances. Though generally, I find that the factory pattern always lends itself to boilerplate code in Java due to the lack of metaclasses.

So something like (module Exception handling and assuming that for each Foo class there is a FooCommand class)

```
 public class AbstractFoo {

     public ICommand createCommand() {
         return Class.forName(this.getClass()+"Command").newInstance();
     }

 }
```

and calling `createCommand()` on `Fetcher extends AbstractFoo` creates an instance of `FetcherCommand`.

Is that what you're looking for?